# Opening a port with iptables doesn't work

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I want to open a port on Debian with `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT`, but it's not working. When I scan the localhost:

```
root@debian:~# nmap -p 80 localhost

Starting Nmap 6.00 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-08-27 12:38 CEST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00033s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): 127.0.0.1
PORT   STATE  SERVICE
80/tcp closed http

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.14 seconds
```

I can't connect with netcat:

```
root@debian:~# nc -vv localhost 80
localhost [127.0.0.1] 80 (?) : Connection refused
sent 0, rcvd 0
```

But it's on the iptables:

```
root@debian:~# iptables -L
...
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:80
...
```

I've also opened the port to the internet with NAT on my router.

I'm using Debian 3.2.0-4 on i368.

Comment: Not a Stackoverflow (aka programming question), but one for SuperUser.SE.

Answer (score -1):

You need something to listen this port to accept connections. Web server for example.

Run this to see if you have a running server that listen 80 port:

```
netstat -ntlup | grep 80
```